# How to test a function call using Python and unittest library

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I just had a question on how you write a test for the following function? Here is my test for the part that is covered, but I am not sure how I would change the test to cover the print statement and calling the `get_employee_name` function again. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: function to test]

Here is my code to test the covered part:

```
DATA = {
"employee_name": "Brian Weber",
"minutes": 120,
"task_name": "Surfing",
"notes": "These are my notes.",
"date": "2016-12-25"
}
​
​
class WorkLogTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_employee_name(self):
        with mock.patch('builtins.input',
            return_value=DATA["employee_name"]):
            assert worklog.get_employee_name() == DATA["employee_name"]
```

Comment: ...really?! Well, under what circumstances do you think those lines would be exercised?

Comment: Well if there was no input then that part of the code would run. Sorry new to testing here.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. If you want to cover those lines, you need to write another test with *different* input data. This will demonstrate why your current implementation is broken. Also, note that recursion isn't the best way to do this; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761.

Comment: Ok so would I use side_effect attribute to use different input data? I'm just confused on the syntax on how I would write the test.

Comment: Have you tried that? What happened?

Comment: I ended up using a while loop with continue if the user didn't enter anything. I'll post the answer

Comment: But that doesn't tell you how to *test* it in cases where the first input isn't valid - the test shouldn't care whether it's recursive or iterative.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what about this? with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["", "Name"], return_value=DATA["employee_name"]):    assert worklog.get_employee_name() == DATA["employee_name"]

Comment: Just try it, and find out!

Comment: I did and it worked

Comment: Welp, question answered.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I had was using recursion if the user didn't enter anything. So I refactored my code to use a while loop using *continue* if there was no user input.
Here is the new code and the test covering all lines:

```
def get_employee_name():
    """Prompt the employee for their name."""
    while True:
        employee_name = input("Enter employee name: ")
        if len(employee_name) == 0:
            print("\nYou must enter your name!\n")
            continue
        else:
            return employee_name

def test_get_employee_name(self):
    with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["", "Brian Weber"],
        return_value=DATA["employee_name"]):
        assert worklog.get_employee_name() == DATA["employee_name"]
```